# Assume a and n are integers, n>1. Prove that the equation ax≡1 (mod n) has a solution if and only if a and n are relatively prime.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

It is an iff statement therefore the proof must be shown to be correct in both directions. I am having trouble with the forward direction.

Comment: The forward direction is the easiest. Try to prove any common divisor of $a,n$ must divide $1$ (see Paul's answer). For the other direction, see [Bézout's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity),

Answer (score 0):

If $ax \equiv 1 \mod n$, then $ax - 1 = kn$ for some $k$, or $ax + kn = 1$. Any common divisor of $a$ and $n$ must also divide $ax + kn$.